# Why does not rsubgroup initialize Java?

Tags: java, r, rjava

I am working with R 4.2.1, 64bit, Windows 10.

while calling library rsubgroup, I get an error:

> library(rsubgroup)
> Loading required package: foreign
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rsubgroup’:
> .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rsubgroup', details:
> call: .jinit(parameters = parameters)
> error: Unable to create a Java class loader.

rJava loads without problems.
I have installed Java 1.8.0_341 and JDK jdk-18.0.2
I have set-up manually JAVA_HOME and PATH variables.

Any hints what can go wrong with .jinit?
many thanks!

Solved, caused by my comp installation: R is installed in C:.../ProgramFiles that is write-protected (accessible only by "admin"); rJava and rsubgroup installed in the ...Users personal library. While moving all installation (core R, libraries) to writable disk, all starts to work. Apologies for this dumb question but I leave it here - perhaps could help somebody in future...